# Can't find connection string in application config, but running the project works fine

Tags: c#, entity-framework, c#-interactive

I'm trying to use the C# Interactive with Entity Framework but it's giving me the following error:

> No connection string named 'PortalSelfServiceEntities' could be found in the application config file.
>     + System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ConnectionHasModel()
>     + System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
>     + System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.get_ObjectContext()
>     + System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ExecuteSqlQuery(string, Nullable, object[])
>     + System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ExecuteSqlQueryAsIEnumerator(string, Nullable, object[])
>     + System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.ExecuteSqlQuery(System.Type, string, Nullable, object[])
>     + System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalSqlNonSetQuery.GetEnumerator()
>     + DbRawSqlQuery.GetEnumerator()
>     + List..ctor(IEnumerable)
>     + System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable)

It looks like it couldn't find my connection, but the WebConfig is fine. If I run the project, everything works fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: A connection string named PortalSelfServiceEntities. That's what you're missing.

Comment: But where? 
The connection string PortalSelfServiceEntities is defined in Web.config.
The error says "... could not be found in the application config file.". 
What file is this one?